# Dúvida sobre processos em linguagem c

Tags: c, processo

Gostaria de saber de alguma biblioteca em c, que possa me servir para criar um programa que veja os processos em execução...tipo o `system("ps")`, EU gostaria de ver se um programa está sendo executado e caso não esteja, então executá-lo.

Ah e o windows.h não serve, vou usar em Linux.

Comment: C não é o mais indicado para tal, tem certeza _mesmo_ que precisa ser em C? De toda sorte, creio que deva ter algum `/dev/...` com os processos que estejam rodando. Só abrir para leitura esse "arquivo"

Comment: Tah beleza valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os diretórios /proc/n (onde n é um número) contêm informações sobre os processos em execução.

Supondo um processo com pid 1234, o arquivo /proc/1234/cmdline é um arquivo texto que contem a linha de comando que originou processo.

Comment: Caramba, valeu. Sabia da proc mas nunca tinha visto o cmdline. Me ajudou bastante